# Is there a shortcut / an app to center the mouse on the current window?

Tags: mac, mouse, cursor

I'm currently using 2 screens for work and I CMD-Tab a lot. But I always have to move the mouse to the other screen.

Is there a shortcut / an app to center the mouse on the current window?

Answer (score 2):

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com) can be setup to do this. I know this is a heavy weight solution for a simple task. However, if your already have KM or if you find value in it for automating other tasks,  it is a great option.

Here is how to set it up:
[image]

Note: this is centered. The (0,0) is relative to the center of the window.

Comment: I made a correction. Originally answered this to center to the screen and not to the **current window** as requested.

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool, then add a keyboard/trackpad shortcut

[image: cursorposition]

Comment: This won't move the mouse to the middle of active window but to fixed location.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek see checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but couldn't find a simple solution even in 2020, so I have written [a tiny app](https://github.com/eucrasia/MoveCursorToCenterOfActiveWindow) to achieve my use case.

You can grab the app (.zip file containing an .app file) from the link below:
https://github.com/eucrasia/MoveCursorToCenterOfActiveWindow/releases/tag/v0.1